# PayPal, wrong return to store URL when payment fails (PrestaShop module)

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop-1.7

I am using sandbox from PayPal (PrestaShop PayPal module) and experiencing issue with URL when payment fails.

When the payment fails I get this message "Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time" with a button that says "Return to Store".

When I click the button URL is:

```
https://shop.mydomain.comindex.php/?controller=order&step=1&token=EC-7S820809X23746729
```

As you can see "/" is missing between ".com" and "index.php"

How I can correct it?

Thanks

Comment: It might be quicker to ask PrestaShop. This is a configuration problem not a programming problem.